# OpenGL rendering not working on Linux machine (windows renders) --- probably related to cmake script (See Updates)

Tags: c++, linux, opengl

I am working on a homebrew graphics engine using OpenGL. I use c++, cmake, glew and wxWidgets. Until now I just worked on a windows machine and everything was fine. Now I tried to port to linux. The problem is now, that everything seems to work, except for rendering. I used an extremely simple shader:

```
#VERTEX // ----------------------------------------------
#version 430 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 VertexPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 VertexNormal;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 VertexTexCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position         = vec4(VertexPosition,1.0);
}



#FRAGMENT // --------------------------------------------

#version 430 core

out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
    FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);  
}
```

On Windows I can render a simple red square without any issues. On Linux, nothing, just the clear color (Backface culling disabled). I also tried switching the clear color every frame to see if the context is bound correctly and the swaps are working. I got the expected flicker screen, so context and missing swaps are not the issue. I also inserted a check for GLErrors and got none. The compiling of the shaders seems to work as expected and the program runs without any exception or other problems, except for the missing output. I also read in another thread where the same problem occurred on OS. Problem was, that there was a call to glEnableVertexAttribArray without a VAO bound. But that is not the case for me. Here is a code snippet how I generate my objects:

```
// Create VAO
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &pVAOHandle_r);
    glBindVertexArray(pVAOHandle_r);

    // Create VBO
    glGenBuffers(1, &pVBOHandle_r);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pVBOHandle_r);

    // Transfer data
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, NumVertexAttribFloats * pVertices_cr.size() * sizeof(F32), VertexArray.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    // Set Attributes
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0,
                          3,
                          GL_FLOAT,
                          GL_FALSE,
                          NumVertexAttribFloats * sizeof(GLfloat),
                          0);

    U16 AttribNumber = 1;
    GLuint Offset = 12;

    if(pVertices_cr[0]->HasNormal())
    {
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(AttribNumber);
        glVertexAttribPointer(AttribNumber,
                              3,
                              GL_FLOAT,
                              GL_FALSE,
                              NumVertexAttribFloats * sizeof(GLfloat),
                              (void*)Offset);
        ++AttribNumber;
        Offset += 12;
    }
    if(pVertices_cr[0]->HasColor())
    {
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(AttribNumber);
        glVertexAttribPointer(AttribNumber,
                              4,
                              GL_FLOAT,
                              GL_FALSE,
                              NumVertexAttribFloats * sizeof(GLfloat),
                              (void*)Offset);
        ++AttribNumber;
        Offset += 16;
    }
    if(pVertices_cr[0]->HasTexCoord())
    {
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(AttribNumber);
        glVertexAttribPointer(AttribNumber,
                              2,
                              GL_FLOAT,
                              GL_FALSE,
                              NumVertexAttribFloats * sizeof(GLfloat),
                              (void*)Offset);
        ++AttribNumber;
        Offset+=8;
    }
```

And here the rendering call:

```
    glBindVertexArray(mVertexMeshReference.GetVAO());
//  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,mVertexMeshReference.GetVBO());
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureReference.GetHandle());

    glDrawArrays(mVertexMeshReference.GetGLPrimitiveType(),
                 0,
                 mVertexMeshReference.GetNumPrimitives() * mVertexMeshReference.GetNumPrimitiveVertices());
```

I wasn't sure if I have to bind the VBO again, so I tested it, did not make a difference.

There is also one difference: on Windows I am building static and on linux dynamically. I am not sure if it might be related to the used libs. Maybe some are missing, but I would expect the linker to complain about it. I also checked which GPU OpenGL is using, cause I got an onboard chipset too, but the output showed the right one. So far I have no clue what might be the issue. Maybe somebody finds an error, that is not relevant on Windows but on linux. Please let me know if you need other code snippets. Hope you can help me.

------------------- UPDATES --------------------------

I will list the results of any suggested solutions here, so that you don't need to read all posts and its comments.

Outputs from OpenGL:

```
   glGetString(GL_VENDOR) = NVIDIA Corporation
   glGetString(GL_RENDERER) = GeForce GTX 980M/PCIe/SSE2
   glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) = 4.50 NVIDIA
   glGetString(GL_VERSION) = 4.5.0 NVIDIA 370.28
```

**Found out the samples have the same problem!**
In one of the comments I said the samples are working. I was wrong. They worked when I used my own build of wxWidgets. But I got other issues with my wxWidgets setup and cmake which were solved by using the libs from the ubuntu repository. Now I copied the penguin example and wrote a cmake file. I have exact the same problem here, everything seems to work except for the penguin, which is missing. So I guess the problem is somewhere in my cmake script and not related to the program itself.

Here is the script (ignore the 2 commands for the minimal wxWidgets sample):

```
 PROJECT(Sample)
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
SET(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)


SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++14 -Wall  -Wno-long-long -pedantic -D__WXGTK__")

find_package(wxWidgets COMPONENTS gl core base REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(OpenGL)
include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})

add_executable(Minimal
   minimal.cpp)

target_link_libraries(Minimal ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(Penguin
   opengl/penguin/penguin.cpp
   opengl/penguin/dxfrenderer.cpp
   opengl/penguin/penguin_trackball.o)

LINK_DIRECTORIES(opengl/penguin)

target_link_libraries(Penguin
    ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES}
    ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY}
    ${OPENGL_glu_LIBRARY})
```

**UPDATE 2**

Now I am 99% certain that it is related to my cmake script. I switched back to my own build wxWidgets. With it (Version 3.1) I am able to build the penguin sample with the provided makefile and I can see the penguin if I run the program. If I build the same files with my cmake script shown above, everthing compiles, but the penguin is missing!

So what am I doing wrong in my cmake file? What's missing? Maybe somebody can copy the script and try it on his own machine?

Comment: Sry, my fault. But I have written a small preprocessor for my shaders which allows me to reuse Code by using includes etc. It also automatically includes the Version directive. I added it into the original post to avoid future irritations. Sry for that.

Comment: Eh, no worries.  Nuking my now-obsolete comment.

Answer (score 0):

If it runs on Windows but not in Linux maybe your driver is not able to run that OGL version.

Which wxWidgets version do you use? Before wx 3.0 only OGL 2.1 was available. With wx 3.1 the OGL version is only limited by the OS driver, but you should ask for the version you plan to use.

Have you tested wxWidgets OGL samples?

Comment: current Version of wxWidgets is 3.0.2. (Ubuntu). The only sample i have run is the penguin example, and it was fine. But I think it is an quiet old sample based on older OGL versions. I ll try the other ones, if you think one of them relies on the current OGL Version. 
When I use the OpenGL command to get the current Shading language Version it says 4.5. I am not totally sure, but I think if the Driver is not working correctly it should show an older Version, or not?

Comment: Get the current OGL version inside your wxWidgets app. The returned version depends on context creation. OGL context creation and its options have been changed in wx 3.1

Comment: used glGetString(GL_VERSION) and it returned 4.5.0 NVIDIA 370.28. Added an Update section in the original post, where you can see what I have tried and what were the results. Listed some other results there too.

Answer (score 0):

Is that really all of the vertex shader? I haven't used Glew or wxWidgets myself, so I don't know if they insert additional code somewhere before it's compiled, but I assume there is a "in vec3 VertexPosition" somewhere.

Never expect the locations for your vertex attributes to always be the same, unless you've put them at fixed locations by using [glBindAttribLocation](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glBindAttribLocation) before linking, or by using layout qualifiers in the vertex shader. Use [glGetAttribLocation](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetAttribLocation) to let glEnableVertexAttribArray and glVertexAttribPointer know for sure where they are. If whatever you're trying to render worked on Windows, this might be the issue.

Comment: Hi, well no, ist not the whole Shader, I have written a small preprocessor which handles includes, so I don't have to repeat Code in every shader. Was to lazy to copy the included stuff. I will edit it and put the included lines into the starting post. Sry for that